# Exporting specific objects using ObjectId to a JSON file

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to export three entries (as identified by ObjectId) from my mongo database into a single JSON file using mongoexport.

I have tried the following commands, but continue to get an "error validating settings":

```
mongoexport -d my_db -c records -q '{_id : ObjectId("123456789")},{_id : ObjectId("10274829479273")},{_id : ObjectId("3749297573927")}' -o user_example

mongoexport -d my_db -c records -q '{_id : ObjectId("23789569127394723")}','{_id : ObjectId("10274829479273")}','{_id : ObjectId("3749297573927")}' -o user_example

mongoexport -d my_db -c records -q '{_id : {$in: [{"23789569127394723", "10274829479273", "3749297573927"}]}' -o user_example

mongoexport -d my_db -c records -q '{_id : {$in: [{ ObjectId("23789569127394723"), ObjectId("10274829479273"), ObjectId("3749297573927")}]}' -o user_example

mongoexport -d my_db -c records -q 'db.inventory.find( { _id: { $in: [ 23789569127394723, 10274829479273, 3749297573927 ] } } )' -o user_example
```

I have been able to extract single entires.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid) from the documentation there `{ "$oid": "593548455198ab3c09cf7369" }`. Also noting that none of the values supplied in your question are valid for an `ObjectId`.

Comment: The article you linked to describes how to export only one entry, I am trying to export multiple. My code attempts are based on the linked example.

Comment: You can still use `$in` to specify multiple values. The answer shows the usage of the Extended JSON syntax to represent the `ObjectId`, which is the basic part of your question.

Comment: Thank you Neil. Could you please provide an example?